# Opening file outside IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I would like to know if there is a way to open files which are not located in an `IsolatedStorage` on a WP7 device ? Internals are not really well documented so...

Comment: seems unlikely, as it wouldn't be very 'isolated'

Comment: Yay, but maybe there is a possibility to hook on an internal open function.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

As a developer using the official Windows Phone 7 developer framework, there is no way to access files that are stored outside of isolated storage. In the Mango framework there is an additional AppData location, but this is also sandboxed and is used for deploying SQL CE data to.

Answer (score 2):

You can get images from either the media library or the camera using their respective Choosers: PhotoChooserTask (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask(v=vs.92).aspx) and CameraCaptureTask (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask(v=VS.92).aspx).

These are the only files that are accessible that are not in your app's IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 7.1 / Mango, system data (like [Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contacts%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)) is shared using the [`PhoneDataSharingContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.phonedatasharingcontext%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). However, there is no indication that third party developers will be able to expose there data using this class and certainly no documentation for it yet.

My guess that it is somehow registered in the application manifest. However, unless it's supported your application won't get approved, even if you do find out how to do it yourself.

Comment: 7.1 documentation (pre-release) specifically states that Contacts is read only.

Comment: I assumed that it was, but read-only data sharing is still data sharing.

Answer (score 0):

with xna, you can access (read-only) the application folder using TitleStorage.OpenStream()